# How to add customized jar in Jupyter Notebook in Scala

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need to use a third party jar (mysql) in my Scala script, if I use spark shell, I can specify the jar in the starting command like below:

```
spark2-shell --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar --jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar
```

However, how can I do this in Jupyter notebook? I remember there is a magic way to do it in pyspark, I am using Scala, and I can't change the environment setting of the kernel I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution now, and it is very simple indeed as below:

1. Use a toree based Scala kernel (which is what I am using)
2. Use AddJar: in the notebook and run it, the jar will be downloaded and voila!

That's it.

```
AddJar http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar
```

Comment: Please, note that is required to add `%` sign before AddJar. That is `%AddJar http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar`

Comment: @mdivk Is there a way to do this without using Toree?

Comment: @coder1416, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854636/how-do-i-import-classes-from-one-or-more-local-jar-files-into-a-spark-scala-not/65395750#65395750 for a clean Almond version.

Comment: how to specify a path to jar if it's local?

Comment: When I use %AddJar in a jupyter cell it says *Line magic Function NOT FOUND*! Any ideas?